# Angular ag-grid: set gridOptions from @input fields

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Goal: Wrap ag-grid-angular component, use data from @input to set gridOptions.

```
//wrapper component
// .html 
<ag-grid-angular
         [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
         [columnDefs]="..."
         [rowData]="...">
</ag-grid-angular>

// .ts this works
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  private gridOptions = {animateRows: true}
}

// this does not work (rows are not animated)
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() rowAnimation: Boolean = false
  private gridOptions = {}
  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.rowAnimation) {
       this.gridOptions['animateRows'] = true
    }
  }
}

// component using wrapper
// .html
<app-grid [rowAnimation] ="true"> </app-grid>
```

Issue is most likely related to gridOptions binding before the @input value is set in the non-working example.  But not sure how to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using below code

grid component template file

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-theme-fresh" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
[animateRows]="animateRow">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

grid component ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-my-grid-application",
  templateUrl: "./my-grid-application.component.html"
})
export class MyGridApplicationComponent {
  private gridOptions: GridOptions;
  @Input("animateRow")
  animateRow: boolean = false;
  constructor() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
      enableSorting: true
    };
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      { headerName: "ID", field: "id", width: 100 },
      { headerName: "Value", field: "value", width: 100 }
    ];
    this.gridOptions.rowData = [{ id: 5, value: 10 }, { id: 10, value: 15 }];
  }
}
```

in my app.component.html

```
<app-my-grid-application [animateRow]="true"></app-my-grid-application>
```

hope this will help you let me know if any issue

thanks